# AngularJS Бесконечный цикл при вызове функции

Tags: angularjs

Пробую вывести значения из `$scope.records`, но происходит переход в бесконечный цикл:

```
<p ng-bind="record(event.rid)"></p>
<div ng-repeat="rec in records">
{{ rec.filename }}
</div>
```

Функция:

```
$scope.record = function(rid) {
    console.log('Отправляем: '+rid);
    $http.get('http://syncmobile.com/device/record/'+rid)
        .then(function success(response) {
            console.log('Ответ: ',  response.data);
            $scope.records = response.data;
        }, function error(err) {
            console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
        });
};
```

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Где я накосячил и как вывести полученное значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но происходит переход в бесконечный цикл:

Ну да, логично.

> ```
> <p ng-bind="record(event.rid)"></p>
> ```

На каждый digest вызывается функция `record`

> ```
> $scope.record = function(rid) {
>     console.log('Отправляем: '+rid);
>     $http.get('http://syncmobile.com/device/record/'+rid)
> ```

которая посылает ajax-запрос, ответ на который

> ```
>         .then(function success(response) {
>             console.log('Ответ: ',  response.data);
>             $scope.records = response.data;
>         }, function error(err) {
>             console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
>         });
> };
> ```

снова выполняет digest-цикл.

Ты заваливаешь сервер запросами, а тут постоянно крутится diget-цикл.

Можно поставить жирный костыль в виде

```
<p ng-init="record(event.rid)"></p>
```

но правильно будет подумать, что за данные и где тебе нужны и запрашивать их в правильном месте.

Comment: Ситуация такова, что из таблицы №1 происходит выборка, и в некоторых случаях нужно один из её параметров (rid) передать в функцию, которая возвращает строку данных из таблицы №2. Как-то так.